# Which software to create mockups for webdesign

Tags: website-design, mockup

I used to use AdobePhotoshop for this purpose but after months i realized that it's not the best tool for this, does anyone recommend a good tool for webdesign mockups

Comment: I think it is perfect tool for such purposes. At least you need to do this once and then just change one layer or smart-object.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for mocking up web sites is HTML and CSS.

Beyond that, a good tool is the one you like to use. People use PhotoShop, Fireworks, The GIMP, Inkscape, Illustrator, Sketch, Pixelmator, Axure, and the list goes on and on. We can't really answer the question for you as it will depend on personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

It's either Adobes Fireworks or Photoshop, both fit well. Photoshop has more features to make more complicated graphics so you dont need to jump in and out of program to get something cool done, but in the other hand Fireworks has better layer management and styles.

Personally I first used Photoshop then changed to Fireworks and now I am again using Photoshop, mostly because I feel like I have more artistic freedom in it.